How to get an object from library override collection for local use?
Imagine you have a setup like this:

Let say I want to have a local copy of one camera. How it supposed to do?
If I duplicate camera, it stays inside library override:

Is there a one-button solution for this?

Select the camera you wish to convert and go to Object > Relations > Make Local... > Selected Objects and Data. Note that if you were to choose Selected Objects instead, your "object" block would convert, while your "data" block would not.

